# Could not get unknown property 'sourcesJar' for object of type org.gradle.api.publish.maven.internal.publication.DefaultMavenPublication

Tags: java, gradle

When build my Gradle Java project with Intellj. I get this error
[image]

But when build this project with command line `gradle clean build`, it success. How to solve this issue

Comment: Are performing a clean build with IntelliJ, also?

Comment: if intellij build success, intellij will show build success. I try another gradle version but have not fixed yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue. In Intellij Ultimate go to File/Setting/Build, Execution, Deployment/Gradle, Choose Use local Gradle distribution and set Gradle home to compatible gradle directory. Similar to Intellj Community
 [image]